# How dynamically add an event to a form when it is created? Which event is responsible for the creation new form?

Tags: .net, winforms

I want to dynamically add an event to a form when it is created.
I want all forms (of different types) to have some an event. (for example writing its data to file before closing).

My main form will create other forms. Here is example of my Main method:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    var mainForm = new MainForm();
    Application.Run(mainForm);
}
```

How can i do it without changing type of my forms? (even main form).

Answer (score 0):

All forms have a FormClosing event, so you can just hook up that event to a stubbed method to handle it:

```
  var mainForm = new MainForm();
  mainForm.FormClosing += FormClosing;
  Application.Run(mainForm);
}

static void FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
  MessageBox.Show("Closing " + ((Form)sender).Name);
}
```

Comment: Yea, i know it. But how to hook up FormClosing event to all forms which are created
 by the main form. And i dont have access edit MainForm class

Comment: @MeisterLuvin The second line shows how to hook it up.  Where ever you create a form that needs that code, you write it like that.  Otherwise, it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I just can't edit my MainFrom class (for some reasons), so i can't hook up an event with a new form when i create it.

Comment: @MeisterLuvin `can't edit my MainFrom class`  clearly that's a different issue that you would have to resolve.  You can't edit code if your program is running.